# "a job offer and to a question" typo

Tags: bug, status-declined

Looking at [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14633/blender-transcoding), the close statement (shown in the comment) has a little typo:

"This question appears to be off-topic because it is a job offer and to a question."

Should be:

"This question appears to be off-topic because it is a job offer and **not** a question."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a close notice - it is a **custom** close reason, which someone made a typo in, and others have selected as well.

The actual notice, now that the question is closed says:

> This question does not appear to be about Blender within the scope defined in the help center.

The comment with the typo is there as well.

There is nothing to fix it, except from the typing skill of the original closer that wrote that custom close reason.

Comment: Alright thanks, I don't really know how this system works :)